# Why does SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED) prevent display power-off?

Tags: winapi, sleep, suspend

I'm attempting to keep the system on while allowing the display to power off, to allow a download to finish while the system is unattended. To achieve this I call:

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
```

whenever I get data from the download. However, this seems to prevent display power down as well (the display dims per its configured dimming timer, but never completely turns off). According to [the MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208(VS.85).aspx), this should only happen if I also pass `ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED` - why is it being blocked anyway?

Note that when I stop calling `SetThreadExecutionState`, the display does not start powering off again; I have to terminate the program to allow the display to turn off. However, shouldn't it only have persistent effects if called with `ES_CONTINUOUS`?

I'm using Windows 7, if it matters. I'm unable to test on other versions at this time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - it appears [the bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9853&q=screen%20blanking&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone) wasn't in my code :)

Answer (score 1):

if you call this function without ES_CONTINUOUS, it will not continue counting the idle timer for system and monitor. so you must pass the parameters with combination by ES_CONTINUOUS. for example you can call 
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS);
instead of 
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);

Comment: Hi, that was not my original problem - but the premise of the question is flawed, so I'll petition the mods to delete the question.